# Linearly independent columns of matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to get a (mxn) matrix_A from input and:

1. Find m linearly independent columns of it and put them into another matrix_B;
2. Put the remaining columns of matrix_A into a matrix_N;
3. And also I need to know the index of those columns I put in matrix_B and matrix_N so I can access them later to change the columns (the indexes can be in an array as long as I can use that to find the columns in the original matrix_A).

Example:

If I have:

```
matriz_A = [[-3. 1.  4. 0. 0.], 
            [ 1. 0. -1. 1. 0.], 
            [ 1. 0.  1. 0. 1.]]
```

I need matrix_B to be like:

```
matrix_B = [[1. 0. 0.], 
            [0. 1. 0.], 
            [0. 0. 1.]]
```

and matrix_N to be:

```
matrix_N = [[-3.  4.], 
            [ 1. -1.], 
            [ 1.  1.]]
```

And also I need to know that indexes of matrix_B are [1, 3, 4] and indexes of matrix_N are [0, 2].

How can I make that in Python? I'm using numpy to get the matrix_A from input as a matrix of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to find the vectors is to use `sympy`. It allows to find the index of the first linearly independant vectors. In your case, the first linearly independant are the 3 first columns.

```
import sympy
import numpy as np

matrix_a = np.array([[-3, 1, 4, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
echelon, index = sympy.Matrix(matrix_a).rref()
```

The `index` variable is a tuple of the linearly independant columns. Let's check that `index` is `(0, 1, 2)`

```
>>> index
(0, 1, 2)
```

To finish, we have to define `matrix_b` and `matrix_n`:

```
matrix_b = matrix_a[:, index]
n_index =  np.setxor1d(np.arange(matrix_a.shape[1]), index)
matrix_n = matrix_a[:, n_index]
```

Finally let's verify:

```
>>> matrix_b
array([[-3,  1,  4],
       [ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  1]])

>>> matrix_n
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. How can I use that same index to separate an array like
b = np.array([-1, - 3, 0, 0, 0]) in two arrays?
In this case, using the same index, they would be c = [-1, -3, 0] and d = [0, 0].

Comment: You're welcome! 
Using the same index and n_index as defined in my answer:
c = b[index] and d = b[n_index]